# jQuery - .on() troubles with "click"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an event for my jQuery/PHP to load more content on scroll down. But I've run into some troubles about my .on() event.

I've created a function (which is the following code you see, I just removed the function functioname{}), which is called when the bottom of the page is reached.

My problem is that with .on() you have to add a "click" property, which is kinda hard for me, because it has to load *without* the click. Is there a property that makes it run the .on() when I've called the function?

```
$("#container").on("click", ".box", function(event){
    alert("hej");

 $.post("site/scroll.php?mabid=" + $mabid,
  function(data){
    if (data != "") {
    alert($(".box:last").attr("mabid"));
    $(".box:last").after(data); 
  }
 });
});
```

The reason I'm using .on() is because it has to add a jQuery plugin to the new created elements, which is *.box*, which makes it have the right layout. The plugin I'm trying to bind to the new created dom elements is this: http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

**UPDATE**

I don't have troubles loading the content. I have troubles adding the jQuery plugin Wookmark to the NEW DOM elements. Which means that it's messy and looks very very bad.

Please read the small description of WookMark plugin on their website. It's a plugin that makes *.box* act like on pinterest.com or wookmark.com where they fit-into eachother.

Right now the new DOM elements just inserts and looks messy, WITHOUT the plugin activated.

**UPDATE2**

After some communication and misunderstandings the problem is solved by just adding the Wookmark plugin to the new elements in the $.post(); like:

```
$.post("scroll.php?...", function(data){

  if(data != ""){
   //add the new dom elements, with .after(), .append() or something else.
   //add the needed effects to the new dom elements. For example with wookmark:
   $('.box').wookmark(//wanted effects); where .box is the dom elements I've created.
  }

});
```

Thanks for the help to everyone, especially FelixKling and Oscar!

Comment: Is your problem loading of the data or applying the plugin to the new data? It seems like you are looking for infinite scrolling: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+infinite+scroll. As for applying the plugin: Only apply it to the new elements.

Comment: No. My problem is that I have to add the Wookmark plugin to newly created DOM elements.

Comment: So, what's the problem with calling `$(data).wookmark()` or calling the the plugin on all elements after you added the new ones to the DOM?

Comment: OMG it's clear, the OP wants to interact with DOM objects and jQuery on() needs an event for work, so the OP needs to work with on() but with a kind of "ready" event (which is not supported)

Comment: @FelixKling Lol, how embarrasing. It's working with just adding the $('.box').wookmark({}); in the $.post(); after the data is added. I thought you had to make it with on or something like that.

Comment: Not at all. It's the same as the example on the page (basically): `$('#myContent li').wookmark({offset: 2});`. Select the elements and apply the method, done :)

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah. I see. I don't know what I've been thinking of. (Been working to much today maybe). It's one of those errors, that makes you laugh when you solve it :o)

Comment: Yeah, breaks are good from time to time ;) Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all you have to do, once you got the new data, is applying the plugin to the new elements.

Either apply it directly to them:

```
$(data).wookmark();
```

or select all of these elements once you added the new data to the DOM:

```
$('.box').wookmark();
```

That said, I don't know what happens when you apply the plugin multiple times to the same elements. Maybe it is better to only apply it to the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if im getting it correctly however did you know you can call .click() of an element, like doing `$('.box).click()` which will act as if you clicked the element.

Comment: you don't understand question then ;-) sorry

Comment: @Kolind: To be fair, it is not clear what your actual question is (without your additional comment). The `click` event handler does not seem to have anything to do with applying the plugin. You should clarify it.

Comment: @FelixKling That's part of the question. Others, like Oscar, did manage to tell that .on() didn't work for this task. Which I thought, so fine, he found another way to do it, which I'm testing right now.

Comment: @Kolind: Well, the event handler you posted seems to load the new data and hence it seems that you have a problem with it. The sentence *"My problem is that with .on() you have to add a "click" property, which is kinda hard for me, because it has to load without the click."* also indicates that you have a problem with loading the data. But as far as I understood, you already solved that part... anyways, as I already said, just apply the plugin method to the new data you loaded, inside the handler that processes the new data.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think we understand each other. But as I wrote in the comments to my question, it's working now, just by doing as you told. I just didn't know you could do it that way. I apologize!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery "live" (deprecated) or "on" works just with click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup events.

But there is a solution, if you just need to use `$('selector').on()` or `$('selector').live()`

Use this library:

**LiveQuery:** https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

```
$('selector').livequery(function(){
  // Here goes your on() logic.
});
```

Comment: I'll try that one. It seems like it's what I need. Let me get back to ya.

Comment: @Kolind No problem, just tell me.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's what I need. Let me clear out the question with new information. Please hang on.

Comment: Are you sure? it works in lots of cases. Can you please create some jsfiddle example to test there?

Comment: It's working now. I just did as FelixKling told: To add the plugin to the new DOM elements in the $.post(); I'll update my question to the correct.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the .scroll() event. 
try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
     alert('window scroll');
     // write your fetching data part here
});
```

UPDATE:
try a custom event approach:

```
// bind the "applyWookmark" event 
$("#container").on("applyWookmark", ".box", function(event){
    // this will reapply the plugin
    $('.box').wookmark();
}); 

// after loading the data
// fire the custom event
$.post("site/scroll.php?mabid=" + $mabid,
    function(data){
    if (data != "") {
        alert($(".box:last").attr("mabid"));
        $(".box:last").after(data);  
        // fire event
        $('.box').trigger('applyWookmark');
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it though...

Comment: I don't think I've been clear enough. I don't need the scroll part. I've already made that. I need the new content loaded to have the same properties like the rest. Which is a jQuery plugin for example.